# Android: reload the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, start-activity

I have the following situation:

- Activity A
- Activity B (marked on manifest as singleTop)

When I go from A to B, I call B.startActivity setting the flag

```
"FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT"
```

(in this way when already open I don't recreate the activity).

When from B I come back to A, i call A.startActivity so another activity "A" is started.

So, when i do these steps a lot of time after 20 times, android destroy all my activities and an exception is generated.

Question: how I can do to open the activity A only one time reloading the existing one from onCreate?

thank you

Comment: use A.startActivityForResult(B), in B, setResult, finish, in A, onActivityResult, refresh views.

Comment: i've add a simple example but in my case is not so...

Comment: my case is the following: activity A call activity B (opening a new activity). activity B call activity C (opening a new activity). activity C is closed and reopen activity A... so i get 2 activity A and 1 acitvity B

Comment: or other case: activity A call activity B (new activity, ok)... throught menu of activity B i call activity Z (new activity). from activity Z i recall activity A (singlTop so i recall the existing one). form activity A i call another time activity B... in this case i get: 1 activity A, 1 activity Z and 2 activity B

Comment: why reorder_to_front ? why not call A with single_task ? or even finish C and B ? circular navigation is not recommended.

Comment: Intent intent(A.this,B.class);starActivity(intent); finish();

Comment: i've choosed to use reorder_to_front because using single_task ihad problem when my activity is sent to background... with single_task, on resume of application the activity is not shown correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You may do it by override method onNewIntent, and add to Activity A or B in AndroidManifest.xml: android:launchMode="singleInstance"

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
     // do something to reload....
    }
```

It mean whenever you startActivity(intent) to A or B, the old instance of A or B will do something to reload.
Hope it help you.